# PHP remove page name Regex - preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have this url (several similar ones)..

```
images/image1/image1.jpg
images/images1/images2/image2.jpg
images/images2/images3/images4/image4.jpg
```

I have this regex: but I want it to strip away the image name from the string:

```
<?php $imageurlfolder = $pagename1; 
  $imageurlfolder = preg_replace('/[A-Za-z0-9]+.asp/', '', $pagename1);?>
```

the string would look like the url's above `images/images2/images3/images4/` but without the `image4.jpg`

hope you can help

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if `dirname()` is applicable here. But have you just tried adapting your regex to simply use `'jpg'` instead of the `'asp'`? The `.` should be `\.` however, and a `$` appended at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this particular purpose function [dirname()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) would be sufficient:

```
<?php echo dirname('images/images2/images3/images4/image4.jpg'); ?>
```

Would return:

```
images/images2/images3/images4
```

Comment: This is one of the coolest functions I have seen :-) I am an asp programmer and this is just NEAT!! thanks...

Comment: Welcome to the PHP world, Gerard! We're having fun here! ;]

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the [dirname](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) function

for instance (from that page)

```
dirname("/etc/passwd")
```

would print

```
/etc
```

Comment: +1 Beat me to it.  `basename()` and `dirname()` are indispensible.

Answer (score 1):

A quite straightforward way to do it:

```
preg_replace("#(?<=/)[^/]+$#","",$your_string);
```

It will remove everything between the last / and the end of the string.

Edit: as many peopole pointed out, you can also use dirname which might proof faster…

Comment: Thanks, I went for the dirname example